# I am having same Row count of dataGridView even after deleting rows in excel (database) file

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, rowcount

I have used dataGridView1.Rows.Count but its giving me Row count of 25 while currently I am having 4 rows in Excel (data base) file. Previously I had 25 rows in excel but after deleting 21 rows it is not showing me updated number of rows. In dataGridview its showing only four rows and count is incorrect. While I also want to remove empty rows in dataGridView

[image: data]

```
DB_Connection db_obj = new DB_Connection();
        DataTable dtable = db_obj.GetData();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dtable;
        int count = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
        MessageBox.Show(count.ToString());
```

Comment: Are you calling again the above method after deleting the rows from excel or you are just asking for rows count?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you refresh your gridview after deleting the rows in excel. Further I would recommend you to always work on the DataSource, so that your grid just present the data. In your case your DataSource is the DataTable. So try the following:

```
int count = dtable.Rows.Count;
```

If there are 25 rows as well, make sure you delete the rows and not just the content.

Comment: I have already tried  int count = dtable.Rows.Count; and refreshed the dataGridView as well but it does not work.

Comment: @HassanSheikh Looks like you don't delete your rows and just delte their content. Please debug and watch which values are stored in your DataRows with index > 3